# Git push origin when creating a new branch automatically merges into master

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm a complete beginner with Git and Gitlab. I've been trying to create a "develop" branch, and it is created when I used the checkout command to create the branch.

```
$ git checkout -b develop
```

Then I pushed the changes into origin

```
 $ git push -u origin develop
```

The problem is that it automatically merges the new branch into master, and I don't want this to happen.

Comment: May you describe all actions you have made? This is definitely not enough to merge the branch in usual workflow, you did it basically right. Also do not use images, put the code here with proper formatting: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Sure, I edited the post and put the code. These are actually the only two commands I used. I'm not sure why it's automatically merging every new branch I create into master automatically(I tried with multiple branches).

Comment: This is not normal behaviour. Maybe you have strange push hooks on the server acting behind the scene? You should ask your GitLab admin for help, if they can.

Comment: What's the output of `git status` ? The first line will mention if `develop` is set to track `origin/develop` or `origin/master`

Comment: "On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean" This is the output when I run git status. I should mention also that I'm the maintainer of this project so there is no admin I can ask for help.

Comment: When you say, "Then I pushed the changes into origin" what changes are you referring to? Did you make any new commits on `develop`? If no, then my answer applies. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because you haven't committed anything yet. If you start with branch `master` and create a new branch called `develop`, at that moment the two branches are identical. If you push out `develop` the branch on the server is still identical to `master`. When you view a branch you will see all the commits on that branch, and many clients will also display other branches that are on that same commit, so you'll see that `master` and `develop` are both on the same commit.

As soon as you add commits to either `master` or `develop`, they will no longer show up this way.